# Can't see DataStax in Services

Tags: cassandra, datastax

First I had DataStax 3.7 installed and everything was fine but later I have downgraded to 2.2 and now I have reinstalled datastax 3.7 but i can't see it in services. I can open my datastax and connect to external clusters but I can't start my cassandra server and so Can't connect to local host.

How to solve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide some more information about your environment?   I'm assuming you are in a linux environment and using datastax community edition (dsc22), and datastax distribution of cassandra (datastax-ddc, 3.7).  Are you on a debian/ubuntu environment?  A key difference is of course the package names.   Are you saying the 'cassandra' service is missing or not running?

Comment: Thanks for response
Mine is Windows, Datastax 3.7

Comment: Also When i am trying to run it manually by going in to bin directory:
It's returning the following error--
Starting with legacy startup options
Starting Cassandra Server
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

Comment: Oh, interesting, possible the default memory options may have changed from release to release.  Do you not have 2GB of free space on your system?

Comment: Yes I do, is there any thing i have to change to increase VM memory

Comment: How much memory does your system running cassandra have (if its a VM how much much memory are giving it currently)?

Comment: I am running it on my own machine not on any VM. Mine has 8GB RAM